# How type this correctly with TS and generic Prisma models

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-generics, prisma

[Need help to type this code correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e69mG.png)

I got this code, but my problem is that I use `(prisma as any)[model.toLowerCase()]`.
I want to get a string of any model name, that might be in my Prisma models, then make any crud function on it. for now, this code is working but I don't use typescript here well.

This is my type utils as well:
`export interface createInputMap { user: Omit<Prisma.UserCreateInput, "id">; }`
`export interface models { user: User; }`

I just made a static model interface that contains the model names.
I don't want to use it like that but I don't find any other type from Prisma that contains the model names and their values.

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)